# Vue JS fading animation with smooth height

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, animation

I have a block when clicked it opens when clicked again closes I want to apply an animation to this block, I want to apply an animation like this

[image]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="show = !show">Click me</button>
    <div v-show="show" class="anim-block"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.anim-block {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

You can also look at [my code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-fire-eqsyo)

Comment: something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-silence-pveph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just a bit of CSS.

Essentially just use your parent anim-block as a mask and add a child div containing your content.

### Child

`position: absolute` = So that it doesn't move with the parent animation

`left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` = To center it within the page (according to your current code sandbox layout)

`width: 280px; height: 300px;` = Set the dimensions of the window

---

### Parent

`position: relative` = To keep the child on the parent, not the page (absolute positioned elements get their origin from the closest relative positioned parent)

`overflow: hidden` = To mask out everything outside it while it animates

`width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0;` = Set the starting state of the animation

`transition: all 0.3s;` = Transition the width and height when they change (can also set width and height independently but "all" is nice and succinct

---

### Vue Component

Lastly, just add a dynamic class on your parent component when show = true.

```
<div :class="`anim-block ${show && 'open'}`">
```

With the final state of your animation in the .open class:

```
.open {
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

### Final Result

Template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="show = !show">Click me</button>
    <div :class="`anim-block ${show && 'open'}`">
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque
          beatae, recusandae laborum nihil, natus placeat aut facere reiciendis
          esse cumque dicta quas possimus qui maxime asperiores sed a
          repudiandae praesentium.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
<style scoped>

.anim-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: rgb(194, 209, 223);
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.anim-block.open {
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.anim-block .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px auto;
}

.anim-block .content p {
  color: rgb(34, 39, 53);
}

</style>
```

---

Side note: this is my first post, so sorry if my explanation is unclear. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!